# str_replace with whole words only

Tags: php, mysql, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to take a string, remove a list of words and any numbers, and then use the result in a MySQL query.

It will echo out the word I am trying to isolate, but when I place that word equal to the string, it returns false and won't query.

```
$remove_odonyms=preg_replace("/\b(st|street|rd|road|ln|lane|ter|terrace|ave|avenue|blvd|boulevard|ct|court)\b/", "", $search);

function remove_numbers($string) {
$num = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
return str_replace($num, '', $string);
}
$street_only=remove_numbers($remove_odonyms);
```

So for the string `$search="60 main street"` `echo $remove_odonyms` is `"60 main"` and `echo $street_only` is `"main"`.

But they won’t query, and they won’t do

```
if($street_only="main"){ echo "true";}
```

**Edit:**  The query I am doing is

```
$query="
SELECT * FROM column WHERE number='$int' AND odonym='$odonym' AND street_name='$street_only'
";
```

It returns nothing.  But when I change it to `street_name="main"`, it returns the result I am looking for.

Comment: Have you any error? looks working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one extra space so you need to trim to remove space. so before query use trim() to remove space and match exact word in query.

```
$street_only = trim($street_only);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out a little more, you can do a couple things:

```
// Case sensitive string (you may or may not have a upper/lower, but the function is here to see both...)
$search         =   '16 Main Street';
// added case insensitive on the chance there are uppers
$remove_odonyms =   preg_replace("/\b(st|street|rd|road|ln|lane|ter|terrace|ave|avenue|blvd|boulevard|ct|court)\b/i", "", $search);

function remove_numbers($string) {
        // remove all numbers
        return trim(preg_replace('/[0-9]/','',$string));
    }
// Presumming you are storing all lower, force lowercase
// This will echo "main"
$street_only    =   strtolower(remove_numbers($remove_odonyms));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$textString ="tim timtim lovetim hitim wholetim byetimbye";
$text = preg_replace('/\btim\b/', 'pankaj', $textString);
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 0):

you're leaving you're self wide open for sql injection, btw.... as you can see, there are many ways to do this..

```
<?php

$str = '120 taco bell bvld. 123';  

$str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-z ]/','',$str);
$str = str_ireplace(array('street','road','rd','ct','court','bvld'),'',$str); 
$str = trim($str); 

$arr = preg_split('/\s/',$str);

$just_street = join(' ',$arr);

print $just_street; 

?>
```